# What is the correct way to pull a remote branch to a local branch using libgit2sharp?

Tags: libgit2, libgit2sharp

### Goal

As part of a tool I'm building, I am exporting a GitHub repository using lib2gitsharp.

I'd like to pull the repository, all tags, and all origin branches at the time of archiving, to ensure they're preserved.

### Progress So Far

- ✔ I am able to clone the repository and its tags
- ❌I am unable to bring down the branches from origin into the local repo.

### Question

Conceptually within libgit2sharp, what needs to be done in order to retrieve a branch from the remote origin and ensure that it is available locally?

I think that it's a combination of a fetch and a merge, but I have had no such luck combining those operations for a successful outcome.

Comment: I am seeing this may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337677/libgitsharp-checkout-remote-branch

Since that answer is from several years ago, I will confirm whether or not it is accurate still. If it is, I'll redirect there and close this question.

Comment: Update: the solution there is still relevant, so I'm voting to close. Sorry, I'd missed it in my initial search.

Comment: @DanielWiddis that is the link I reference in my comment above. I've voted to close this topic as linked to that.

Comment: that comment was auto-generated by my close vote and will be auto-deleted if the question is closed.